# Edit Help file outside doc directory causes tags not to work when copying in

Tags: vim, tags

I've created a help file under $VIM\vimfiles\doc. After nearly deleting it I wanted to edit it elsewhere and then copy it to the doc directory and then regenerate the tags.

The tags are generated , I can see them in the tagfile, but the file that I copy in, unique name, when I do :h sfcontents for eg and then ctrl-] on a tag I get the error "e426 tag not found"

If I edit the file in the $VIM\vimfiles\doc directory and then run either :Helptags or :helptags $VIM\vimfiles\doc the tag jump works

I can't attach a file but the help file looks something like

```
vim: filetype=help foldmethod=indent foldclose=all modifiable noreadonly
Table of Contents *sfcontents* 
*sfsearch* - Search specific commands help 
|count-matches-of-pattern|
|match-specific-column|
...
==============================================================================
count-matches-of-pattern
*count-matches-of-pattern*
:%s/pattern//gn 
counts the number of the matches in a file eg count the number of spaces
not at the beginning of a line 
:%s/[^ ]\+//gn
==============================================================================
*match-specific-column*  
c=column l=line v=virtual column, ie ignore tabs and special chars
/\%5cx will match all occurrences of x at column 5.  
/\%>5vx will match all occurrences of x after character 5. If there is a
tab character between poition 1 and position 5 the /\%5>v. against the
following line with a tab at position 4 will return the number 4
123 45
/\%>4cx\%<7cx will match all occurrences of x after column 4 and before
column 7

Or use |YankMatchesToReg| eg YankMatchesToReg /\%265v./x which copies
column 265 to register x across the whole file 
==============================================================================
...
vim:tw=88:ts=4:ft=help:norl
```

I've ended up doing the archive out of the vim directory with the following;

```
nmap <leader>c :sp C:\Progra~2\vim\vimfiles\doc\commands.txt<cr>
nmap <leader>co :call BackupCommands()<cr>

function! BackupCommands()
     exec "silent! !copy C:\\Progra~2\\Vim\\vimfiles\\doc\\commands.txt        
     C:\\Progra~2\\vimutils\\vimtips\\commands_back.txt"
     exec "helptags C:\\Progra~2\\Vim\\vimfiles\\doc\\"
endfunction
```

I'd prefer to copy from the archive to the doc directory rather than the other way round. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight from Vim's help files (:h write-local-help):

```
The first line is actually the only one for which the format matters.  It will
be extracted from the help file to be put in the "LOCAL ADDITIONS:" section of
help.txt |local-additions|.  The first "*" must be in the first column of the
first line.  After adding your help file do ":help" and check that the entries
line up nicely.
```

**Short**: You're missing `*sfsearch.txt*` as first characters in your file!

Vim wont add to `|local-additions|`, therefore wont be searched, assuming your tags file was generated correctly. You can verify that by opening the `tags` file in the `/doc` directory and finding your tags there manually. There should be a `tags` file in each correctly helptagged `/doc` directory (`:helptags <doc-dir>`).

Comment: Ahah that explains why the help file I was copying from wasn't working either.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, fear of "nearly deleting" a file is not a proper reason for editing in another location and copying back and forth. In fact, you've now introduced another risk of accidentally losing file contents via a wrong copy command.

Instead, use proper version control (Git, Mercurial, etc.), or, if that's too heavyweight, you can try my [writebackup plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1828), a pure Vimscript implementation. With the companion [writebackupToAdjacentDir plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3107), you can even backup to other directories.

That said, tag jumping should work even with your copy regime, provided that you run `:helptags $VIM\vimfiles\doc` *after* copying your help file to that exact location.

Comment: Version control is next on the list however I use something as a backup / version control but it doesn't have proper access to the Vimfiles directory.

Thanks for the confirmation that it should work as I thought. I'll keep trying.